# Generative phonology and segmental phonology

Tags: phonetics, phonology

How can I know the difference between generative phonology and segmental phonology?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_%28linguistics%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generative phonology is a meta-theory of phonology (i.e. the application of generative grammar to the study of phonology), but segmental phonology is the study of a specific area, namely segments, as opposed to prosody (such as syllables and tone). Thus one can study segmental phonology generatively or non-generatively, and one can study prosody generatively or non-generatively. While there is a rather hard distinction between generative and non-generative approaches to language, the segmental / suprasegmental distinction is more a matter of personal interest. Indeed, especially since the advent of autosegmental phonology (e.g. Goldsmith dissertation *Autosegmental phonology*), the distinction between segmental and suprasegmental aspects of representation has been blurred, so that only moras, syllables and feet are resolutely suprasegmental.